# Is it possible to change the PageControl position?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have an UIPageViewController with the PageControl on it and I want to change it position.

But I'm working hard over it almost 2 days and nothing. I cannot change it's Y position.

I tried with

```
view.frame.origin.y
```

And

```
view.layer.position.y
```

I've tried ALL stack overflow answers. Also I've tried with the 'for sub in view.subviews' (I took it from the SO answers). It did not helped me, either.

So, I want to know, is it possible?

I have one UIPageViewController and two ViewControllers: ViewController and ContentViewController. In the ViewController I implement all things, PageViewController also, but in the ContentVC I just manage with my InageView content.

My source code is long, so if you need to look at sone exact part, just ask me and I'll provide it to you.

Comment: I don't think its possible to cleanly change the UIPageViewController's pageControl position. Most solutions are going to require private knowledge of the UIPageViewControllers setup. However setting up your own UIScrollView based PageViewController with your own UIPageControl wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @RyanPoolos I thought about this case, but I did not sure is it a professional way or not?

Comment: @Orkhan if default behaviour doesn't meet your requirements you can take `UIScrollView` with paging enabled and use own pageControl in any position

Comment: you get to determine how professional it is  If you do a good job your customers would never know. @sage444 has some good tips.

Comment: @RyanPoolos I did it with the method which you said ;)) but I have a little question, how can I prevent dragging on the last view? Look at the image, please: http://imgur.com/qCDnZWx

Comment: Personally I prefer it. However if you don't, `UIScrollView` has properties to stop bouncing. Set the `alwaysBounceHorizontal` to false and it should stop when it hits the edge of the `UIScrollView`'s content.